# perforce setup for multiple nightly builds

Tags: perforce, nightly-build

We have a large code base in Perforce.  I would like to do the following nightly, automatically.
- Copy some view of "latest" into two (or more) workspaces, streams, or even just into some other folders not under perforce control.
- Check everything out (if p4 used) and "compile it", (where "compile" may include changing most files, thus the need to have them be writable.
- Rinse repeat the following "night" with a fresh "latest".
I know how to do this via simple copying things out, but would like the nightly modified code to be able to be "seen" from other machines, by other people, thus maybe the stuffing of things back into perforce.
I know how to do this with P4 workspaces.
Just wondering if p4 streams (tasks?) are a better approach, or for any other alternate recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Using workspaces is indeed what you want to do.  The benefit of using streams would mostly be in simplifying the task of generating and managing these workspaces.

Do you want to keep the changes made by the build machine isolated from the mainline that everyone else uses?  Should those changes also be isolated from other builds?  Or do you want to make sure that everyone gets the changes ASAP and that they make their way into all other variants of the code?  These are good questions to ask as you're setting this up and the answers should influence what you do.

Comment: I want to keep the changes made, even leaving some files checked out, isolated from the mainline.  Then every night those changes will be reverted, sync in new files, "compiled" them (which modifies them), rinse, repeat.  That's why I was thinking streams.

Comment: In a streams model, I think what you'd want would be to define those files as "isolate" paths (so changes to them are isolated from the mainline).  It sounds like you're basically doing the same thing over and over (and touching a lot of files) rather than doing task-based development (which implies a one-off task that touches a small subset of files) so a task stream wouldn't be appropriate; this would be a standard long-lived stream that is dedicated to the task of storing build artifacts.